# What happens to local variables in this recursive call?

Tags: lua

In a complicated code, I found a weird behavior: apparently Lua doesn't treat local variables the same as C and Java (I'm not surprised but I don't know HOW it treats them anyway!)

I read [PIL](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html) and [Lua-users.org](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ScopeTutorial) but none doesn't mention what happens to local variables in recursion. It caused me to develop the following test code:

```
function addN(n)
    local ret=""
    if n>0 then
        ret=ret..addN(n-1)
        print("for n="..n.." ret='"..ret.."'")
    else
        print("n reached 0")
    end
    return ret
end

print("Final result='"..addN(9).."'")
```

Expected result:

```
Final result='987654321'
```

But I get:

```
Final result=''
```

Why? How can I reach the expected result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not actually concatenating `n` anywhere. Try something like:

```
ret = tostring(n)..addN(n-1)
```